# IP address or not?

Tags: code-golf, string, number, decision-problem

Your network scanning tool is annoyingly picky about input, and immediately crashes if you feed it an IPv4 address that contains improper characters or isn't properly formatted.

> An IPv4 address is a **32-bit numeric address** written as four numbers separated by periods. Each number can be **zero to 255**.

We need to write a tool to *pre-validate* the input to avoid those crashes, and our specific tool is picky: A *valid* format will look like `a.b.c.d` where a, b, c and d:

- Can be a `0` or a natural number with **no leading zeros**.
- Should be between 0 - 255 (inclusive).
- Should **not** contain special symbols like `+`, `-`, `,`, and others.
- Should be decimal (base `10`)

**Input**: A string

**Output**: Truthy or Falsey value (arbitrary values also accepted)

**Test Cases**:

```
Input            |  Output  |  Reason
                 |          |
- 1.160.10.240   |  true    |
- 192.001.32.47  |  false   |  (leading zeros present)
- 1.2.3.         |  false   |  (only three digits)
- 1.2.3          |  false   |  (only three digits)
- 0.00.10.255    |  false   |  (leading zeros present)
- 1.2.$.4        |  false   |  (only three digits and a special symbol present)
- 255.160.0.34   |  true    |
- .1.1.1         |  false   |  (only three digits)
- 1..1.1.1       |  false   |  (more than three periods)
- 1.1.1.-0       |  false   |  (special symbol present)
- .1.1.+1        |  false   |  (special symbol present)
- 1 1 1 1        |  false   |  (no periods)
- 1              |  false   |  (only one digit)
- 10.300.4.0     |  false   |  (value over 255)
- 10.4F.10.99    |  false   |  (invalid characters)
- fruit loops    |  false   |  (umm...)
- 1.2.3.4.5      |  false   |  (too many periods/numbers)
- 0.0.0.0        |  true    |
- 0.0 0.0.       |  false   |  (periods misplaced)
- 1.23..4        |  false   |  (a typo of 1.2.3.4)
- 1:1:1:1:1:1:1:1|  false   |  (an IPv6 address, not IPv4)
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes will win!

> **Note for the users** - if anyone wants to add some test-cases, they're welcomed (by suggesting an edit).

Comment: Suggest testcases: `1.1.1.1.1`, `1.1.1.1.`, `.1.1.1`, `1..1.1`, `1..1.1.1`, `1.1.1.0`, `1.1.1.-0`, `1.1.1.+1`, `1.1.1.1E1`, `1.1.1.256`, `1.1.1.0x1`, `255.255.255.255`, `0.0.0.0`, `'or 1=1--`, `<empty string>`, `1 1 1 1`, `1,1,1,1`.

Comment: I'd suggest test cases like `Hello, World!`, `1.1.1.1.1`, `1.-1.1.1`

Comment: Suggest adding test cases "1.2.3.4.5" (to rule out too long IPs) and "999.0.0.0" (to rule out too large IPs).

Comment: Possibly slightly picky, but you should probably refer to "IPv4 addresses" rather than "IP addresses" - or at least, mention somewhere that you just mean IPv4 addresses - otherwise 1234:5678::1 ought to be a valid IP address (whereas from the description it's clear that that's not intended :)

Comment: Why are leading 0's disallowed in octets especially if one of your restrictions is base 10?

Comment: 0 is a valid IPv4 address too, which expands to 127.0.0.1

Comment: 1.2.3 is accepted by ping too - it expands to 1.2.0.3 and 1.2 expands to 1.0.0.2

Comment: @Criggie The premise isn't to *actually* check all *real* IP4 rules (like the ones you mentioned), it's to ensure that the input string doesn't crash some other (presumably badly written) app that only allows input in a very specific form. Also, we're not going to change the rules of a challenge that already has 30+ answers.

Comment: @BradC Fair enough - I'm just  pointing out that this is not 100% reflective of the real world.   Its a bit specalised.

Comment: @Criggie Worth noting that the RFC declares that "Addresses are fixed length of four octets". I think the fringe cases you're referencing are more specialized than this challenge.

Comment: A test case similar to one presented by @tsh would be `1.23..4` (e.g. a typo of `1.2.3.4`); there are four digits and three periods, and there are no leading or trailing periods, but it's still not valid (other than via Criggie's expansion, which would still be a different IP from what was likely intended: `1.23.0.4` vs `1.2.3.4`)

Comment: Ipv4 addresses can also be written as a longint... such as [http://16843009](http://16843009), should that be allowed here?

Comment: @nl-x It very heavily seems like the intent of this challenge is to parse ip addresses in dot-decimal notation.

Comment: To IP or not to IP?

Comment: “fruit loops” (umm...)

Comment: @Criggie Actually, RFCs specify that a valid IPv4 address is either of the form n8.n8.n8.n8, n8.n8.n16, n8.n24 or n32, each n being written either in decimal, octal or hexadecimal (thus 0x7f.001 is a valid IPv4). BTW, 0 is not 127.0.0.1, it's 0.0.0.0, meaning "any address", which on your machine resolves to any or all of your interfaces IPv4 addresses. This challenge focuses on only one of of those multiple notations and, obviously, the resulting codes should NOT be used in real life programs (use dedicated functions like POSIX's `inet_addr()`). True IPv4 validation may be another golf though.

Answer (score 25):

## X86_64 machine code: <del>18</del> 16 bytes

Edit: This answer doesn't quite work, as

1. I am using `inet_pton` from the standard C libraries, which means I need the extern. I didn't include the extern in my byte count though.
2. I used the red zone as a result for the actual address, but called a function which also could've used the red zone. It fortunately doesn't on my machine, but some odd standard library build might use it which could cause undefined behavior.

And yeah, the whole thing is pretty much being done by an already written function

Anyway, this is what I got: `48 89 fe 6a 02 5f 48 8d 54 24 80 e9 00 00 00 00`

Assembly:

```
section .text
    extern inet_pton
    global ipIsValid

ipIsValid:
    mov rsi, rdi
    ;mov rdi, 2 ; change to 10 for ipv6
    push 2
    pop rdi ; thank you peter
    lea rdx, [rsp - 128]
    jmp inet_pton
```

## Explanation:

Take a look at `inet_pton(3)`. It takes a string IP address and puts it in a buffer you can use with `struct sockaddr`. It takes 3 arguments: the address family (`AF_INET` (ipv4), 2, or `AF_INET6` (ipv6), 10), the ip address's string, and a pointer to the output. It returns 1 on success, 0 for an invalid address, or -1 for when the address family is neither `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` (which will never occur because I'm passing a constant to it).

So I simply move the string to the register for the second argument, set the first register to 2, and set the third register to the red zone (128 bytes below the stack pointer) since I don't care about the result. Then I can simply `jmp` to `inet_pton` and let that return straight to the caller!

I spun up this quick test program to test your cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>

extern int ipIsValid(char *);

int main(){
    char *addresses[] = {
        "1.160.10.240",
        "192.001.32.47",
        "1.2.3.",
        "1.2.3",
        "0.00.10.255",
        "1.2.$.4",
        "255.160.0.34",
        ".1.1.1",
        "1..1.1.1",
        "1.1.1.-0",
        ".1.1.+1",
        "1 1 1 1",
        "1",
        "10.300.4.0",
        "10.4F.10.99",
        "fruit loops",
        "1.2.3.4.5",
        NULL
    };

    for(size_t i = 0; addresses[i] != NULL; ++i){
        printf("Address %s:\t%s\n", addresses[i],
            ipIsValid(addresses[i]) ? "true" : "false");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Assemble with `nasm -felf64 assembly.asm`, compile with `gcc -no-pie test.c assembly.o`, and you'll get:

```
Address 1.160.10.240:   true
Address 192.001.32.47:  false
Address 1.2.3.: false
Address 1.2.3:  false
Address 0.00.10.255:    false
Address 1.2.$.4:    false
Address 255.160.0.34:   true
Address .1.1.1: false
Address 1..1.1.1:   false
Address 1.1.1.-0:   false
Address .1.1.+1:    false
Address 1 1 1 1:    false
Address 1:  false
Address 10.300.4.0: false
Address 10.4F.10.99:    false
Address fruit loops:    false
Address 1.2.3.4.5:  false
```

I could make this much smaller if the caller was supposed to pass `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` to the function

Comment: I love that you did this in asm. And the fact you explained it to those who might not understand it (as well as test code) is even better. Which is not to say that I could have done it in asm; far too many years have passed but I remember enough to see exactly what your explanation (and therefore process) is saying (does). Good work.

Comment: `e9 00 00 00 00` is a `jmp near $+5`, not a `jmp inet_pton`. If you provide opcode, you should include the including `inet_pton` part, not leave a blank

Comment: [15 bytes-TIO](https://tio.run/##TVJdb9MwFH33r7gyG2lZ7CVpBmpTioagj/DA41IhN3EaQ2JbtrsNtfntJU7agqyr@3XOvfaRt8zWp4I5WC6/fl@v7l2r7xn9kUlmWyAVb6pZApcqEHWJVcaLWkGA3ohWK@OW1pVC0XqFRNYyISfTQ1Ez846VpXnafDzgmMbvIxpHNEkjHOJ4ntAoiuksoekHn9OE3tC0j5KHhwEa0ZlPaeyPR3iLaLr2Q@bzPqvMXjholNIWh1GXVcpMsmGh2GR3d2J60EZIV03wY1/k1sKtXeTu1uYSh2dcKPQzaybnbPoJO7PneIEr1liOp1nXBaMolhZZjnK0K4p/MsCldZUFiFRECw6knSUDQW1/lftWA/lyBa3ejq1BQsIB5/LzH8ftAvvOlWCvhCPfGa4heIrIfHNIOwiO7OU3kDXg/gTjO@Hm27oLjs4AKSHIZXB86a9aXJaNs06WF04oCdTxV4d640aCkNz91E5JtGvUljUwqILQ4BZI720NfKtRq569D4Fbfa6y1zFIUMGa5r9JA9Z6bE/USg/ecHfq/9npLw "TIO") 32bit x86

Comment: you should include the extern in the answer title, since the program requires it and it is not available on all platforms.

Comment: poor answer, IMHO, just farming the bulk of the work out to an external function.

Comment: the "mov rdi,2" can be "push 2/pop rdi" for -2 bytes.  Note also that the disassembly is wrong or the code is wrong.  It's either "mov edi" (not rdi) or there's a prefix missing.

Comment: @Logern, the stack frame isn't needed, which makes is only 9 bytes.

Comment: @Logern On my machine (compiling with -m32) I'm getting a segmentation fault after the second call to `inet_pton` somewhere in libc, nice idea though

Comment: This answer is incorrectly scored. The string `inet_pton` **must** be included in the byte count. Furthermore, the export `ipIsValid` needs to be included in the byte count as well, and as such, should be renamed to `f`. I would also suggest adding at least 1 byte for each import and export (i.e., an extra 2 bytes on top of the lengths of the two strings). To see how these strings make it into the assembled result, look at the output of `readelf -s assembly.o`.

Comment: Would `mov rsi, rdi` save a byte if changed into push/pop? Not familiar with x64asm

Comment: “It works on my machine” is the core of this site.  No budges are left unused!

Answer (score 13):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 63 bytes

```java
s->("."+s).matches("(\\.(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\\d|[1-9])?\\d)){4}")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJNb9swDL3nVxDGgtlrREiK3dXN0h2GHXoYUKDALkkOiq10yvwRWHKwoclvzyTZTZxtEGSRfI9PpKmt2AuyzX@eVLmrGwNb62NrVIEfZqN/Ypu2yoyqq/@C2jRSlA7atetCZZAVQmv4JlQFryOAPqqNMPbY1yqH0mLhs2lU9bJYgWhedOSpAE@NzFUmjPzUwQ@g9HdRqPzxaR/D/KTJQxhgcKMjLIXJfkgdBuFyiSFPFpQkq0PI7RmvDmy5zA8LRtJV9NmaUfQaH4PoNPO3nK82UpsvQksN874AgIAhu6XIKPKYBhPrp9xG7tDGncuTxBMoTmMPOwA90wVpZzrWYL/pUMpwyjH@2GVynGKf2N3YMy3wDgfqaZqeEy5SeE4QuMYMcw/xKZLEYYw7n/zdDkmQ8OQWCb3uh1w31Hf75jh7GL22hlxCL/bNUOPrwLEFDP7dL4@8rxtgc0aIczwKfnlz4tdATZI7einKFuDHd@wGvKmb/n35Ed9fBh2d57yu60KKChqp28LYBzB4aej4oftEs57@/FsbWWLdGtxZYbMJgzFL9D2M9biyhTjypBfrk44jt4@nPw)

### Credits

- -1 byte thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)
- [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2) for showing the previously-failing case `.1.1.1.1`.

Comment: You forgot to remove the trailing semi-colon. ;) [And I can verify it works for all test cases, including those in the comments.](https://tinyurl.com/yajlbv4r) Will see if I see some things to golf.

Comment: Failed on `.1.2.3.4`

Comment: Is it allowed to use boolean when explictly require 0/1?

Comment: @l4m2 The original question had Valid/Invalid. So I assume any truthy/falsey value is acceptable here.

Comment: `Output: 0 or 1` and Java has no auto bool->int

Answer (score 12):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 43 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.split`.`.map(t=>[t&255]==t&&[])==`,,,`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBbboMwEPzvKSxUERB4ZRtIgyrzlxP0EyHh8mhT0YDAqjhBD9Aj9iLUdkhiqhXWzM7s4PWH@BJTNZ4Gic993SwtX2aezTAN3UmWUMKnGDzJs1y6LEkKzqXr5oXPeRmGYbk8P@QOBbonQAmwmDghcmjKVOcAqq@pGjMGAlFsZC0AuUrWdx0mhELEIH662BlEoJGKuPxmdSrhEazINE1vA/couA0IeIUKaiOxCHCiNco0x/93wAlgluwBk@0SeLvFuuKVaGx3t8j2YnLHgZ1xtIi6gPVgM10fQZeGu35ElFOMNTFGZMrA0JQV3OADcQpo@/EoqndvQjxDVX@e@q6Brn/zJhhE/SLFKD2a@ChAO/T7/aPOALXe5Pv@8gc)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 46 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.split`.`.every(t=>k--&&[t&255]==t,k=4)*!k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBBbsIwELz3FW5UQVKyK9tJKFFlbrygR4REGkJLg3AUW4h@oA/oE/uR1DYEHLSKNbMzO/H6qzgWqmx3jYaD3FTdVnQnMT@havY7vcY1Vseq/Q61mNcAo9FSj3iWrYTQcS3S6Pmx7l4flgFDNqXIKPKUBjEJWM5NZ4amb6kZcQaKSepkKyDtJe/rhyllmHBMX852jglaZCLOv7k4jfCEXmSe59eBWxReBwp8xxI3TuIJQmY1xi2H@x0gQ@DZFIEOl4DhFpcVe2Kx3x0i3wv0hid@xsIj5gLeg53Y5RFsWTiWLWGCAVjijMSVg7ErL7iCGQ1WuJXtoig/Q0XEnJTyoOS@wr38CBU2xeZNF60OWRaRCRmTv59fc07INlRRFHX/)

used Arnauld's part

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>54</s> <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.split`.`.every(t=>k--*0+t<256&[~~t]==t,k=4)*!k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBBboMwELz3FS6qGgjsyjaQBrXmlhf0GEUKJaRNQQGBFdFLjn1An9iPUNshiVOtsGZ3ZgePP7ND1uXtrpGwrzfFsBVDL9Ieu6bayTWusTgU7ZcrRVoCTKkvX3g8e1wej3IlhAxKEXnT@3J4vls6DNmMIqPII@oExGEJV5M5qrlueRwbAcUwMrQmkJ4p6zsvU8ow5Bg9neQcQ9RIWZx@MyoV8YCWZZIkl4WrFV4WMnzDHDeG4iFCrDnGdQ//M0CMoAIj0NsQcJtijHhuNLant8jWAr1i3/ZYWI26gPVgPRsfQZeGk7olTDAA3RghMWVgYMoyLmBOnRVu63aR5R9uR0RK8nrf1VWBVf3udthkm1eZtdJlsUd8MiG/3z/q9MnW7TzPG/4A)

-2B for `0+t<256`, -1B from Patrick Stephansen, +1B to avoid input `1.1.1.1e-80`

RegExp solution <s>58</s>54 bytes

```javascript
s=>/^((2(?!5?[6-9])|1|(?!0\d))\d\d?\.?\b){4}$/.test(s)
```

Thank Deadcode for 3 bytes

Comment: I have added some test cases!

Comment: This gives truthy for `0.0.0.0`. [Everything else seems to work fine.](https://tio.run/##XVDLboMwELz3K1xUNRDYlW0gDWrNLV/QY1UplEebJgoIrIhecuwH9BP7I9R2SGKqFdbszuyY8Wd2yLq83TQS9nVRDpUYepH22DW7jVzjGstD2X65UqRbgDn15ROPF/fHo/R7IdQRbEXkzW@3w@PNi8OQLSgyijyiTkAclnA1WaKa65bHsRFQDCNDawLpmbK@8zKlDEOO0cNJzjFEjZTF6ZpRqYg7tCyTJLksXK3wspDhG@ZYGIqHCLHmGNc9/M8AMYKKjECnIWCaYox4bjS2p1Nka4FesW97rKxG/YD1YD0bH0GXhrO6JUwwAN0YITFlYGDKMi5hSZ1XrOp2leUfbkdESvJ639W7Enf1u9thkxXPMmuly2KP@GRGfr9/1OmTyu08zxv@AA)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `0.0.0.0` is here true one. Just why SQL injection is here?

Comment: Ah wait, I misinterpret the sentence in the challenge description. `0.0.0.0` is indeed truthy. That will golf my answer as well.. (And what do you mean by SQL injection? :S The link is to TIO with ALL test cases.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Why test case `'or 1=1--` exist

Comment: @l4m2 I added it since we need some testcases that even not looks like an IP address.

Comment: A **reg**ular **ex**pression is called a "regex" or a "regexp"...

Comment: The regex solution looks faulty. Shouldn´t `\\.` be `(^|\.)`? Why the double backslash?

Comment: @Titus edited..

Comment: Since t is already a string, you can save [1 more byte](https://tio.run/##XVBBboMwELz3FS6qCgR2ZRtIg1pzywt6rCqFEtKmRCECK6KXHPuAPrEfobYDialWWLM7s4PHn/kxb4tme5Cwr9dlvxF9J7IO28NuK1e4wvJYNl@eFFkFMKOBfOLJ/P50koHrCiHDSsT@7LbqH29eHIZsTpFR5DF1QuKwlKvJAtVctzxJjIBiFBtaE0hHyvrGZUoZRhzjh7OcY4QaKYvzbwalIu7QskzT9LJwtcLLQo5vWODaUDxCSDTHuO7hfwZIEFRiBDoNAdMUQ8Sx0dieTpGtBXrFge2xtBp1AevBOjY8gi4N3bohTDAA3RghMWVgaMoyLmFBnVfc1M0yLz68loiMFPW@rXcl7up3r8VDvn6WeSM9lvgkIC75/f5RZ0A2Xuv7fv8H).

Comment: Does something involving `>>8` save any bytes?

Answer (score 11):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <strike>39</strike> 36 bytes

```php
<?=+!!filter_var($argv[1],275,5**9);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WW1ExLTOnJLUoviyxSEMlsSi9LNowVsfI3FTHVEvLUtP6////hkbmegZAaAgA)

275 resembles the constant `FILTER_VALIDATE_IP`

5**9 is being used instead of the constant `FILTER_FLAG_IPV4`. This is sufficient, because `5**9 & FILTER_FLAG_IPV4` is truthy, which is exactly what PHP does in the background, as Benoit Esnard pointed out.

Here, `filter_var` returns the first argument, if it's a valid IPv4 address, or false if it's not. With `+!!`, we produce the output required by the challenge.

Comment: Using `5**9` instead of `1048576` saves 3 bytes here: [PHP uses `&` to test the IPv4 / IPv6 flags](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L801-L807), so any number between 1048576 and 2097151 is valid.

Comment: I hereby downvote your answer for being (basically) my answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174470/14732 which was written at 2018-10-22 09:17:34UTC while yours was written on 2018-10-22 09:21:55UTC. Even if I revert the 1-byte optimization given by @BenoitEsnard, my answer is exactly the same as yours in functionality.

Comment: I have to apologise, I didn't see your answer, though at the time I was composing it, there was no submission in PHP on this question (as you said, the time difference is less than five minutes).

Comment: I know, and I understand it. I only noticed yours just now. I can roll back mine, and you keep the optimization. But I don't know if it makes the answer be different enough from eachother.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I wouldn't downvote somebody for that if it's plausible yours wasn't there when they started. With a 5 minute difference, not only is it plausible, it's almost certainly the case, which is apparent even without the author saying so himself.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I agree with Duncan about not downvoting. If it were like half an hour later, that'd definitely make sense, but 4m21s is certainly an acceptable timeframe wherein your answer may not have been submitted yet when oktupol started writing theirs.

Answer (score 11):

### PHP, 36 Bytes

```
echo(ip2long($argv[1])===false?0:1);
```

`ip2long` is a well-known [built-in function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php).

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WWyOzwCgnPy9dQyWxKL0s2jBWU9HWVtFQ0/r///8GemAIAA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: This seems to use uncodumented features present in newer versions (I presume it is from PHP7+). Keep in mind that, for PHP 4 and 5, this does accept incomplete IPs.

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WI7PAKCc/L11DJbEovSzaMFbT3tDKQNP6/38A)

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7146/12130

Comment: @DavidMulder thanks. I edited it to use `php -r`.

Comment: 29 bytes: `<?=ip2long($argv[1])!==false;` Can You give a TiO? From the description, it seems that `ip2long` is not as restrictive as the challenge demands.

Comment: @Titus It is, for newer versions of PHP. It just isn't documented. Newer versions don't accept incomplete IP addresses. Older versions do. I know that some PHP5 versions do accept the partial IP, just don't know all because it isn't documented. This is the only reason why I didn't use this method, and even described it in my answer.

Comment: I tried on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com : it was restricted in PHP 5.2.

Comment: This will give success if you feed it any integer, such as 1 , 2 , etc. Don't think it should. And also if you feed it something as 100.100.100

Comment: @JoKing According to the OP, `0.0.0.0` is a valid IP address. This makes sense as many applications treat it as valid IP address, and also my PHP version treats it as valid. PHP 7.2.11.

Answer (score 10):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Phil H.*

```perl6
{?/^@(^256)**4%\.$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzNDgExFIX3nqKL0pnBmdtfRIQHkZFZ6IqQsZqIZ6@2UuRuvnPynXs/DxcXriObebYLz33bHapOWVc3jZkewdtXePQj8xU/1czfhomQkI4gCcqQWMS8USCS0ApmlQsoaHwpAUUjT6wtE@nWiK@KxmESRiG/J@ick1Kkf063pB/PPz3LJ7bhDQ)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                  }  # Anonymous Block
  /               /   # Regex match
   ^             $    # Anchor to start/end
    @(    )           # Interpolate
      ^256            #   range 0..255,
                      #   effectively like (0|1|2|...|255)
           **4        # Repeated four times
              %\.     # Separated by dot
 ?                    # Convert match result to Bool
```

Comment: Man, I need to spend more time figuring out Perl 6's regexes. I had no either the `%` modifier existed.  I wonder if it tries to checks all `256**4` possibilities?

Comment: Instead of `<{^256}>` you can just convert the range to an array `@(^256)` for -1 char [TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7v9peP85BI87I1ExTS8tENUZPRb/2f3FipYJamoaSgR4YKmlac6EIYQhgCOIUQxYxMjXVQ8KoUma4pAz1jPSM9UxQhHSMdIx1wEJc/wE). By changing the code block to an array it also gets enormously faster (0.4s instead of >30).

Comment: @PhilH Cool, thanks. I tried `$(^256)` but now I realize why this didn't work.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>26</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>22</s> <s>23</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'.¡DgsAì₅ÝAìÃg4)Ë
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Emigna*.
+1 byte for bugfixing test case `1.1.1.1E1` incorrectly returning a truthy result.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXe/QQpf0YsfDax41tR6eC6QPN6ebaB7u/v/fQM/AQM/QQM/I1BQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##XVDBagIxFPyVEApLcd/wkt3o7kGkUL9CelAr0pOgIHpV9OKt9x5671d0/8Qf2SZvV82WEDLzZt4kL6vNdPaxqLf7kVbX86fSo32d4Pf7dbl5qX6uh1P15c/quMyfq0ud1hNtYPoMw7A561RpU1pfKeDrgVrnxMDIcpGDAHGGIjcwuKJ9y2E2yCzyQdNpkaFtbG5snV54QpReluW94RGFe8MUM8zxLpLNQC5oxgZO/8chB7KuD@LuPNQdqJ32RgKOq10Ue4kfuBdnjCPiHxD93U6UZLVWZmiIAhFVyRKYyorSFlSwfvsD).

**Explanation:**

```python
'.¡          '# Split the (implicit) input-string on "."
   D          # Duplicate this list
    g         # Pop and push the length of this copy
   s          # Swap so the list is at the top again
    Aì        # Prepend the alphabet before each item
      ₅Ý      # Push a list in the range [0,255]
        Aì    # Prepend the alphabet before each integer here as well
          Ã   # Only keep those items from the first list
           g  # Pop and push its length as well
   4          # Push a 4
    )         # Wrap all three values on the stack into a list
     Ë        # Check that all three are the same (aka all three are 4s)
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Prepending the alphabet is necessary, because in 05AB1E, `"0"`, `"00"`, `"0e0"`, `"5E0"`, `"-0"` etc. are all the same 'integer' `0`.

Comment: You should be able to use `Ā` instead of `<d`

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I'm afraid it fails for `1.1.1.1E1`, `1..1.1.1`, `1.1.1.1.`, `192.00.0.255`, and `0.00.10.255`. (PS: I've fixed the `1.1.1.1E1` by adding the `þ` to the join-and-equal check.)

Comment: Fair enough, figured I missed something.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn The main issue is 05AB1E seeing numbers with leading 0s equal to those without, even as string. Which is why I use the `DïþJsJQ` check where `ï` cast it to int to remove leading 0s, and `þ` only leaves digits removing things like `E`, `-`, etc. :) The `1š` is for test case `0.00.10.255`, since `00010255` and `0010255` would be equal.

Comment: Yeah I went through the same nonsense, the reversal of all numbers worked pretty well though, except for those cases. Interesting when features beneficial for some problems become almost bug-like for others.

Answer (score 6):

## PowerShell, <s>59</s> <s>51</s> 49 bytes

*-8 bytes, thanks @AdmBorkBork*

*-2 bytes, `true` or `false` allowed by author*

```powershell
try{"$args"-eq[IPAddress]::Parse($args)}catch{!1}
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

try{"$args"-eq[IPAddress]::Parse($args)}catch{!1}

}

@(
    ,("1.160.10.240" , $true)
    ,("192.001.32.47" , $false)
    ,("1.2.3." , $false)
    ,("1.2.3" , $false)
    ,("0.00.10.255" , $false)
    ,("192.168.1.1" , $true)
    ,("1.2.$.4" , $false)
    ,("255.160.0.34" , $true)
    ,(".1.1.1" , $false)
    ,("1..1.1.1" , $false)
    ,("1.1.1.-0" , $false)
    ,("1.1.1.+1" , $false)
    ,("1 1 1 1" , $false)
    ,("1"            ,$false)
    ,("10.300.4.0"   ,$false)
    ,("10.4F.10.99"  ,$false)
    ,("fruit loops"  ,$false)
    ,("1.2.3.4.5"    ,$false)

) | % {
    $s,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $s
    "$($result-eq$expected): $result : $s"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: True : 1.160.10.240
True: False : 192.001.32.47
True: False : 1.2.3.
True: False : 1.2.3
True: False : 0.00.10.255
True: True : 192.168.1.1
True: False : 1.2.$.4
True: True : 255.160.0.34
True: False : .1.1.1
True: False : 1..1.1.1
True: False : 1.1.1.-0
True: False : 1.1.1.+1
True: False : 1 1 1 1
True: False : 1
True: False : 10.300.4.0
True: False : 10.4F.10.99
True: False : fruit loops
True: False : 1.2.3.4.5
```

Explanation:

The script tries to parse an argument string, to construct a .NET object, [IPAddress](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.parse).

- return `$true` if `object` created and the argument string is equal to a string representation of the `object` (normalized address by `object.toString()`)
- return `$false` otherwise

### PowerShell, <s>59</s> <s>56</s> 54 bytes, 'don't use a .NET lib' alternative

*-3 bytes, `true` or `false` allowed by author*

*-2 bytes, thanks to @[Deadcode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179141/80745) for the cool regexp.*

```powershell
".$args"-match'^(\.(2(?!5?[6-9])|1|(?!0\B))\d\d?){4}$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLRToMwFIbveYraVEcjnBQoKCYG44UvIWrIKM4EA1KIJsCz4xlbyNw625vyf/3/c2hbV9@q0RtVlhMryD3pJwosa941dT@zdr1Zvdop2L6dXITJc@TGL3zwBvwS6SPnaZ7mCe/lyFbTaFkPtkVwODb1wIsEeAJ8KShxCGubTvGFxj4I4UHgg7yZcZGV@oCDDwGcAwZdYNxcLQxNLiznRbeATRl6wUgG0mDDsPkvBATy1LdN2@cd9/gP2k5XnEXXRheZp4lQcjCcY4qN47FIENRM5dP2zOKYntKi6T5aUlZVrQ10dz8SQvqnrsXJQC5JP29j2mHqp1brVuX4rNjbTm2U7soWhSt8bUzPImX2XnfV12Lid8tuXGlqjdMv)

Thanks @[Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%c3%a9goire) for the original regular expression.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `|% t*g` since PowerShell will automatically cast the right-hand-side of `-eq` as a string, because the left-hand-side is a string. -- `try{+("$args"-eq[IPAddress]::Parse($args))}catch{0}`

Comment: You can carve 2 bytes from the "don't use a .NET lib" version by using my regex (adapted to the insert-a-period trick, which of course can't be in my version because it's a pure regex): https://tio.run/##fZLRToMwFIbveYraVEcjnBQoKCYG44UvIWrIKM4EA1KIJsCz4xlbyNw625vyf/3/c2hbV9@q0RtVlhMryD3pJwosa941dT@zdr1Zvdop2L6dXITJc@TGL3zwBvwS6SPnaZ7mCe/lyFbTaFkPtkVwODb1wIsEeAJ8KShxCGubTvGFxj4I4UHgg7yZcZGV@oCDDwGcAwZdYNxcLQxNLiznRbeATRl6wUgG0mDDsPkvBATy1LdN2@cd9/gP2k5XnEXXRheZp4lQcjCcY4qN47FIENRM5dP2zOKYntKi6T5aUlZVrQ10dz8SQvqnrsXJQC5JP29j2mHqp1brVuX4rNjbTm2U7soWhSt8bUzPImX2XnfV12Lid8tuXGlqjdMv

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3: <s>81</s> <s>78</s> <s>70</s> <s>69</s> 66 bytes

```
['%d.%d.%d.%d'%(*x.to_bytes(4,'big'),)for x in range(16**8)].count
```

Loop over all possible IPv4 addresses, get the string representation and compare it to the input. It uh... takes a while to run.

EDIT: Removed 3 bytes by switching from full program to anonymous function.

EDIT2: Removed 8 bytes with help from xnor

EDIT3: Removed 1 byte by using an unpacked map instead of list comprehension

EDIT4: Removed 3 bytes by using list comprehension instead of the `ipaddress` module

Comment: I think your anonymous function can just be `[str(ip_address(x))for x in range(256**4)].count`. Also, `256**4` can be `16**8`.

Comment: I like the extemely golfy while practically unusable approach :)

Answer (score 5):

## PHP 7+, <del>37</del> <del>35</del> 32 bytes

This uses the builtin function [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), to [validate that it is an IPv4 address](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).

For it to work, you need to pass the key `i` over a GET request.

```
<?=filter_var($_GET[i],275,5**9);
```

Will output nothing (for a `falsy` result) or the IP (for a `truthy` result), depending on the result.

You can try this on:
<del>http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/639c22281ea3ba753cf7431281486d8e6e66f68e</del>
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff6aaeb2b2d0e0ac43f48125de0549320bc071b4

---

This uses the following values directly:

- 275 = FILTER_VALIDATE_IP
- <del>1<<20 = 1048576 = FILTER_FLAG_IPV4</del>
- 5**9 = 1953125 (which has the required bit as "1", for 1048576)

Thank you to [Benoit Esnard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38454/benoit-esnard) for this tip that saved me 1 byte!

Thank you to [Titus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55735/titus) for reminding me of the changes to the challenge.

---

I've looked into using the function [`ip2long`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php), but it works with non-complete IP addresses.

Non-complete IPv4 addresses are considered invalid in this challenge.

If they were allowed, this would be the final code (only for PHP 5.2.10):

```
<?=ip2long($_GET[i]);
```

Currently, it isn't explicit in the documentation that this will stop working (when passed an incomplete ip) with newer PHP versions.

After testing, confirmed that that was the case.

Thanks to [nwellnhof](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9296/nwellnhof) for the tip!

Comment: Using `5**9` instead of `1<<20` saves one byte here: [PHP uses `&` to test the IPv4 / IPv6 flags](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L801-L807), so any number between 1048576 and 2097151 is valid.

Comment: In newer PHP versions, `ip2long` doesn't allow incomplete addresses.

Comment: @BenoitEsnard Thank you! I've added it to the answer

Comment: @nwellnhof After testing, I confirm that that is the case. However, I don't think it is a good idea to use it, since it isn't explicitly documented.

Comment: `+!!` is not required; the OP now accepts arbitrary truthy values.

Comment: @Titus Totally forgot about this. Thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) / POSIX, 26 bytes

```c
f(s){s=inet_pton(2,s,&s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9fT4MwFMWf6ae4QWfaAdfyZ1PHtq/hw1wMKbA1YYXQ7sWFry62KGruQ3/n5JyTVEQnIcaxpprd9E6qyrx3plU0CXX4oFk@jHdSieZaVrDVppQtnvdEKgOXQirK4EY8cS56WJrDEXZW@jHGa44xxyTjfmj1S4Kcx5gmmD1NBiaY4i854DYxVVaruRKvn9FOzbF7zBzawDTPMZ20i8yh/@wu4n8cfPswncPNhvvEG3Li1W0P1P1I7ngOcqvlR9XW1LDHH1oaZv0gYMTzut4ma@ovNER7WJRvyg/BHOQxBFuxL2N2sq/MtVfAczKMn6JuipMeo1fVRvLSNVJIE9mVLw)

Works as 64-bit code on TIO but probably requires that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char*)` on other platforms.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, if you're on x86, you should probably try in 32-bit mode (`-m32`).

Comment: I got it to work, by passing `s` as a `char*` (no access to a ILP32 system here), and yes, I was mixing up with `inet_aton()`.

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>84</s> <s>79</s> 65 bytes

```cs
s=>s.Split('.').Sum(t=>byte.TryParse(t,out var b)&t==b+""?1:5)==4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFBS8QwFITv/opQZDdhdx9Jm1aLpiDCnjwICp63oZVAaJYkFfbX17Te7Ctzex/zYGZ0OOlgpvM46OcQvRm@j6R1zjakV1NQTYBXNw6RatVopWTFlCp2AT6u1kS6hz2DF2tpVE17ix18@tv7xYeOxqMbI/m5eNKyXVSqPWQZm57uvryJ3ZsZOtrTTNQ5cC6gyEE@ZIz9x5BDARv39ZmnXyA45GWJe@5BrgGIWZhhm8w68S1ywDxkEQKQE4ciJZHAUSbPc8i6XsPejyYS69w1bJUpoUSLm7WVB6@g@utaYrY0q6gecWtaZzGnkMsa0y8)

-5 and -14 bytes saved thanks to @dana!

<s># [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 61 bytes</s>

```cs
s=>s.Count(c=>c==46)==3&IPAddress.TryParse(s,out IPAddress i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcmxCsIwEADQvV8ROkgC9Ui1dKkXEEEQRAoKzpqmEtAEcpehXx@dXN@ztLbkSyYfXuK6ELsPXBwP1TEHuyNOP2/EM8a3ETMWQkNwiDmwtGgsYtcrxO3qNO6nKTkiuKVlfCRykpqYWfxDeFWG6p48u7MPTs6ybqHtNbQaNp2ulSpf)

This is a work in progress. The code use `System.Net` (+17 bytes if you count it). if you wonder why I count and parse:

> The limitation with IPAddress.TryParse method is that it verifies if a string could be converted to IP address, thus if it is supplied with a string value like "5", it consider it as "0.0.0.5".

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412956/what-is-the-best-way-of-validating-an-ip-address)

As @milk said in comment, it will indeed fail on leading zeroes. So, the 61 bytes one is not working.

Comment: @dana great. Nicely done! Four more and it will beat the 61 bytes solutions!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>85 82</s> 81 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

```python
from ipaddress import*
I=input()
try:r=I==str(IPv4Address(I))
except:r=0
print~~r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLboMwELz7K6yoEpDWK9sYGipx6KEHbv2FFFyVQ8AyTpVc8uvUDxJMZVma3Zmdfair@RkHPrdjJ3GNd7vd/K3HE@7Vseu0nCbcn9SozR41dT@os0kzZPT1TddNXU9Gp83nr3gP0rTJMiQvrVTG8hQp3Q/mdtOzdUWWkC32bfY4L@dzwoCVFBgFLmiCbFxxmzmAzbuQF4UXUMiFpx0BXumSNECniv7dh1IGOQfxGio55LAUho6L0hJPELlXVfUoWK3gUXCEL2ih8xTPgRSOY9zF5P86pADCixII3e5Dtgst294Dh@PsFsVaQlf8HHt8RIEdILrdxTOjxqxmhDjsSeyfhy/@RWaSHOg6U@gP4aBiva2A5A8)

[113 byte answer](https://tio.run/##PU/basMwDH3XV4gwsD0yYbtJtwS8x0G@YRs061zmkjrGM6P9@kzNLgiko8uRjtKlfMzRLsu7P@CTHFQPWPKlz@55dxrPUtenEKVt29p/jZMMSqndYc4YMEQc6DNNoUhBQr0C@vPep8JUIQBTDrHIwTlu0nHmJVmpWzn5K3CuUUuICR1WVWXIbDUZTbbRYDrL6QNxccVaG9pYau7BkKUN/YTV31ADmgdWatty7Wpd18H4tgde/CfvJQoF8C@bD/e/AjHU4u5R1MC/B7V8Aw) is deleted as it fails for `1.1.1.1e-80`

Comment: You can golf `print 1*r` to `print~~r`. +1 though, since it seem to work for [all possible test cases suggested thus far](https://tio.run/##XVDLboMwELz7K6yoEpDWK9sYGipx6KEHbv2FFFyVQ8AyTpVc8uvUDxJMZVma3Zmdfair@RkHPrdjJ3GNd7vd/K3HE@7Vseu0nCbcn9SozR41dT@os0kzZPT1TddNXU9Gp83nr3gP0rTJMiQvrVTG8hQp3Q/mdtOzdUWWkC32bfY4L@dzwoCVFBgFLmiCbFxxmzmAzbuQF4UXUMiFpx0BXumSNECniv7dh1IGOQfxGio55LAUho6L0hJPELlXVfUoWK3gUXCEL2ih8xTPgRSOY9zF5P86pADCixII3e5Dtgst294Dh@PsFsVaQlf8HHt8RIEdILrdxTOjxqxmhDjsSeyfhy/@RWaSHOg6U@gP4aBiva2A5A8). PS: Your 113 byte answer fails for `1.1.1.1e-80`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks! Didn't think about such notation of numbers

Comment: Isn't `ipaddress` a Python 3 module?

Comment: @Farhan.K Dunno, but it works in TIO

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
q.
Ê¶4«Uk#ÿòs)Ê
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cS4KyrY0q1VrI//ycynK&input=IjEuMTYwLjEwLjI0MCI=) or [run all test cases](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cS4KyrY0q1VrI//ycynK&input=WwoiMS4xNjAuMTAuMjQwIgoiMTkyLjAwMS4zMi40NyIKIjEuMi4zLiIKIjEuMi4zIgoiMC4wMC4xMC4yNTUiCiIxLjIuJC40IgoiMjU1LjE2MC4wLjM0IgoiLjEuMS4xIgoiMS4uMS4xLjEiCiIxLjEuMS4tMCIKIi4xLjEuKzEiCiIxIDEgMSAxIgoiMSIKXQotbVI=) or [verify additional test cases from challenge comments](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cS4KyrY0q1VrI//ycynK&input=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)

---

### Explanation

We split to an array on `.`, check that the length of that array is equal to `4` AND that the length when all elements in the range `["0","255"]` are removed from it is falsey (`0`).

```
                 :Implicit input of string U
q.               :Split on "."
\n               :Reassign resulting array to U
Ê                :Length of U
 ¶4              :Equals 4?
   «             :&&!
    Uk           :Remove from U
      #ÿ         :  255
        ò        :  Range [0,255]
         s       :  Convert each to a string
          )      :End removal
           Ê     :Length of resulting array
```

Comment: Nice answer. Also [verified for all suggested test cases thus far](https://tinyurl.com/y6wmc838). Curious to see that explanation.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, explanation added. Thanks for those additional test cases.

Answer (score 4):

## ECMAScript pure regex, 41 bytes

`^((2(?!5?[6-9])|1|(?!0\B))\d\d?\.?\b){4}$`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3dToNAEIXv9ylo0oSdKtNdWGooQRKT@gBVr0QTLEtFt0AW6k9/nh13WzXfxZyZM2fmLf/Iu5Wu2t7r2qqQetPU7/J70EktP52lXC@@Wkp3yfV0MjxT6tN0FKaPMy96ggM/mI5lNwBZkRVphmn2AntxHA@T6Q6wb@56XdVrCtipaiXp7NITAHHZaFomPKYq0TIvVFVLCjBK6q1ScZkw2FclHZXQmnBPISbttu96TRVu8n71SjWk7v3yYTF3HHfulrnq5NxxIf5bg/g4cOQzhpyhLxjhkY@McQx8FFeEo48BngthxjitheFpMkZBjD6lGQaCILcY719YPHY2LszAOUEMJmCuCWRWilt7N4pIqbdV76imabvf3wJD@9hiq2OVtQJE8QM)
[Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xFKpgH/1)

I think the logic in this regex speaks for itself, so I will merely pretty-print but not comment it:

```
^
(
    (
        2(?!5?[6-9])
    |
        1
    |
        (?!0\B)
    )
    \d\d?
    \.?\b
){4}
$
```

This can be used to shave 2 bytes off the following other answers:

- [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174478/17216) (Java (JDK))
- [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174456/17216) (JavaScript (Node.js))
- [mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174483/17216) (PowerShell)
- [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174485/17216) (Retina)

Some alternative 41 byte versions:

`^((2(?!5?[6-9])|1|(?!0\d))\d\d?\.?\b){4}$`
`^(((2(?!5?[6-9])|1|(?!0))\d)?\d\.?\b){4}$`
`^(((2(?!5?[6-9])|1)\d|[1-9]?)\d\.?\b){4}$`

Here is an alternative version that allows leading zeros, but does so consistently (octets may be represented by a maximum of 3 decimal digits):

`^((2(?!5?[6-9])|1|0?)\d\d?\.?\b){4}$`

Or allow any number of leading zeros:

`^(0*(2(?!5?[6-9])|1?)\d\d?\.?\b){4}$`

Or if allowed to have undefined behavior regarding leading zeros (as it so happens, a leading zero is only allowed only in 2-digit octets):

`^((2(?!5?[6-9])|1?)\d\d?\.?\b){4}$`

Comment: `\b` and `\B`... it's smart!

Comment: @mazzy Yes, those two really come in handy! I could've used `(?!0\d)` instead, but I like `\B` better!

Comment: The powershell answer doesn't get shorter with your regexp. I'm sorry. Quotes are needed to convert an array to a string. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLRToMwFIbveYraVEcjnLSsoJgYjBe@hEyDW3EmmE3Kognw7HjolmVune1N@b/@/zm0Xa@@dW2WuqoGVpJ70g6UFfW7oeFn0cyXkxffj/zsIs6ekzCd8U52@CXyR87zRb7IcsjyN96qnk2G3vMefI/gCHwqQSYCpIBICUoCwpp6o/mephEIIWEagbqxuCwqc8AhgimcAw5dYJytFscuF5aTyS1gU45eMJKBctgwzP6FgKk69Y1pu7zjHv9B4wzFWXTtdBE7XYSSgxEcU2wcj0WBoG6qnsYzS1N6Sst689GQarVaGwfd3o@CmP6p63HSkUvS2m3MBEz/rPW80Qt8WOx1q9babKoGhSt8b8xYkTJ/p4f6a2/id/vduDLU64df "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy Note that I said my regex "can be used" to shave 2 bytes off your answers: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLRToMwFIbveYraVEcjnBQoKCYG44UvIWrIKM4EA1KIJsCz4xlbyNw625vyf/3/c2hbV9@q0RtVlhMryD3pJwosa941dT@zdr1Zvdop2L6dXITJc@TGL3zwBvwS6SPnaZ7mCe/lyFbTaFkPtkVwODb1wIsEeAJ8KShxCGubTvGFxj4I4UHgg7yZcZGV@oCDDwGcAwZdYNxcLQxNLiznRbeATRl6wUgG0mDDsPkvBATy1LdN2@cd9/gP2k5XnEXXRheZp4lQcjCcY4qN47FIENRM5dP2zOKYntKi6T5aUlZVrQ10dz8SQvqnrsXJQC5JP29j2mHqp1brVuX4rNjbTm2U7soWhSt8bUzPImX2XnfV12Lid8tuXGlqjdMv "PowerShell – Try It Online") - I mean when it is adapted to the same insert-a-period trick.

Comment: The `\.?\b` saved me a byte on my answer too, thanks!

Comment: Saved 3 bytes thx

Answer (score 3):

## [sfk](http://stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html), 176 bytes

* was originally Bash + SFK but TIO has since added a proper SFK wrapper

```
xex -i "_[lstart][1.3 digits].[1.3 digits].[1.3 digits].[1.3 digits][lend]_[part2]\n[part4]\n[part6]\n[part8]_" +xed _[lstart]0[digit]_999_ +hex +linelen +filt -+1 -+2 +linelen
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7BCsMgEER/Zcl1iagJpX6LXZaCppWKlOrBv7dLIDnnMPB2YGembp8xeuwwJ5jY59qev0beqAVCeqVWSV07fI4lEPuv/Ft6lB3WA24H3IknwB4DnGXa7xHEzjkGfMsYzKlECQTcUm4woxHZ0x7DOKu0lnqrVv0H)

Comment: Would first checking the error printout from `nc [addr] 1 -w1` shorten this?

Comment: @Rogem `nc` accepts leading zeroes as well as IPv6 addresses, so I'd still have to handle those - and this is intended more as a `sfk` answer than a shell answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>39</s> 31 bytes

Original version:

```
¬FailureQ[Interpreter["IPAddress"][#]]&
```

Modified version (thanks to Misha Lavrov)

```
 AtomQ@*Interpreter["IPAddress"]
```

which returns `True` if the input is a valid IP address ([try it](https://tio.run/##TY5ND4IwDIb/Clk8@VG7MTTc4GLCDc@EA5EZSeQjY56Mv322U4x50@192q5d37ib6RvXXRpf2m5wlc/d2J@zdTE4Yydr6KxEUeZta808i9rvs@gpJMgDgkRQGsVWyFQBooRYgT4yg4IYFkM3Ujm0J8k3uwJNjjhMQogZQbJCx59l7XApb0IyCmLHQc9pvgb8gD7xrjQlutpH56L7OE7z718aEvGq/Rs)).

In case you insist on getting `1` and `0` instead, then an additional 7 bytes would be necessary:

```
Boole/@AtomQ@*Interpreter["IPAddress"]
```

Comment: Since `Interpreter["IPAddress"]` returns a string for valid input, and some complicated failure object for invalid input, we can test for valid inputs with `AtomQ[Interpreter["IPAddress"][#]]&`, which can be further shortened to the function composition `AtomQ@*Interpreter["IPAddress"]`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5ND4IwDIb/Clk8@VG7MTTc4GLCDc@EA5EZSeQjY56Mv322U4x50@192q5d37ib6RvXXRpf2m5wlc/d2J@zdTE4Yydr6KxEUeZta808i9rvs@gpJMgDgkRQGsVWyFQBooRYgT4yg4IYFkM3Ujm0J8k3uwJNjjhMQogZQbJCx59l7XApb0IyCmLHQc9pvgb8gD7xrjQlutpH56L7OE7z718aEvGq/Rs "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: Fails on an IPv6 address like `2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 15 bytes

```bash
ipcalc -c `cat`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7MgOTEnWUE3WSEhObEk4f9/Qz1DMwM9I1NzIDYDAA)

Outputs exit code 0 for truthy, 1 for falsy.

Comment: The `echo $(($?))` part is not needed since programs are [allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5330#5330) to output their result via exit code.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>93</s> <s>89</s> <s>67</s> 53 bytes

```python
[i==`int(i)&255`for i in input().split('.')]!=[1]*4>_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5dT8MgFH0evwITI63GG6Cg6ZL6tr764tuyuFlZRmwKoTS6X18vzC7m8HHOPede8Od4coOcO/dpaEMZY/PWNs3eDrGw5Z3Uen90gVpqB1x@ikUJo@9tLBiwcnfTbMXuXr28z9hJyPfJ9oa@hcmsySqGM54r82O6Io0vUfiAg3OAoNEZH@nmtd2E4ELKfgRz@Fqc9TXfHvrRzEyAeOIgOEjFGWGilsC5gEqCek4aJFSwELw52jmu9V/1FhQy1HkShypJEAk58Y8mPPLFfshFmpFY2tiO8xXwi1BtequuUR3DZCPtnfPj9V8K9OVLCYz8Ag)

Thanks to Dennis for shaving *another* 14 bytes on the internal comparisons and exit code.

Special thanks to Jonathan Allan for shaving 22 bytes & a logic fix! Pesky try/except begone!

Taking properly formatted strings instead of raw bytes shaves off 4 bytes, thanks Jo King.

Comment: Your check can be golfed to ``i==`int(i)&255` ``. Also, you can force an error with `[...]!=[1]*4>_`, since you're using exit codes anyway. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5dT8MgFH0evwITI63GG6Cg6ZL6tr764tuyuFlZRmwKoTS6X18vzC7m8HHOPede8Od4coOcO/dpaEMZY/PWNs3eDrGw5Z3Uen90gVpqB1x@ikUJo@9tLBiwcnfTbMXuXr28z9hJyPfJ9oa@hcmsySqGM54r82O6Io0vUfiAg3OAoNEZH@nmtd2E4ELKfgRz@Fqc9TXfHvrRzEyAeOIgOEjFGWGilsC5gEqCek4aJFSwELw52jmu9V/1FhQy1HkShypJEAk58Y8mPPLFfshFmpFY2tiO8xXwi1BtequuUR3DZCPtnfPj9V8K9OVLCYz8Ag "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Dennis I don't understand what `>_` does. The bitwise and is quite ingenious though... I was unsuccessful in combining those myself.

Comment: If the `!=` returns False, Python short-circuits and nothing happens; the interpreter exits normally. If it returns True, `>_` raises a NameError, because the variable `_` is undefined.

Comment: Figures I chain comparisons in my answer and then miss the obvious result in your comment. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

## <s>Python3</s> Bash* 60

*Also other shells. Any one for which the [truthy/falsy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/25088) test passes on a program exit code

```
read I
python3 -c "from ipaddress import*;IPv4Address('$I')"
```

### Explanation

The trouble with a pure Python solutions is that a program crashing is considered indeterminate. We could use a "lot" of code to convert an exception into a proper truthy/fasly value. However, at some point the Python interpreter handles this uncaught exception and returns a non-zero exit code. For the low-low cost of changing languages to your favourite Unix shell, we can save quite a bit of code!

Of course, this is vulnerable to injection attacks... Inputs such as `1.1.1.1'); print('Doing Something Evil` are an unmitigated threat!

Comment: (*[Explanation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/explanation#Noun)* it is (not *Explaination*).)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yikes. It was even underlined in red. My browser tried to save me, but I wouldn't listen. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Full programs are [allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5330/48198) to output via exit codes, therefore this could be [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chsyAxJaUotbhYITO3IL@oRIvLM6DMxBEippGZV1BaoqGp@f@/oZ6RnrGeCQA).

Comment: @BMO Interesting. Thanks for pointing that out! I think the problem definiiton changed from "Truthy/Falsy" to also allowing arbitrary output since I posted this, but I could have just not noticed before :)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 49 bytes

Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
s=>[0,1,2,3].map(i=>s.split`.`[i]&255).join`.`==s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJfa8IwFMXf9ymCyGhZvd78c/QhPu5LiGBxrUSypjR1X79LIjLnaGrOU@DHyT335Fx9V@7Y625YtfazHhs1OrXdYUELVvA9fFVdptXWgeuMHg5w2On9K5Myh7PVrb8r5cajbZ01NRh7yppsQYFuECgCE7jIc0LWazL0l/rlkSsZIFLgDMR7AD3XVMb9B4EBh2h1PUnwjpsE0T8cJ5TyiqcclyB@PadA7xRjI3CRCg006KksD@g0GLTCWTByb3Q@CyVRT4D3u06Cfi1@4wJuUyZA8RGaKct0MU1/0QMx1nZuvkHuX5a3WRN/IuhP6tDg@AM)

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 106 bytes

```
func[s][if error? try[t: load s][return off]if 4 <> length? t[return off]s =
form as-ipv4 t/1 t/2 t/3 t/4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7JDoMwDETvfIWFeq2bjS6oyz/0GnFAJWmRaIJMqNSvTyMujTjMwW9mbJPp4t10uilsHe3sHnpqdG/BEHm6QaCvDjUMvu0gGWTCTA68tU3KKDhfYTDuGV4pmZsTXArr6Q3ttO3Hj4Kw40kiSSapJo7UuwAWSo58z5AzFIqVxR@fBDLGUQpUh5yjQIlrkM0s1ZZ1VbVax/dHTNdW3Q2qjIhqeYehVGX8AQ)

Returnd `true` or `false`

### Explanation:

```
f: func [ s ] [
    if error? try [                  ; checks if the execution of the next block result in an error
        t: load s                    ; loading a string separated by '.' gives a tuple   
    ] [                              ; each part of which must be in the range 0..255
        return off                   ; if there's an error, return 'false' 
    ]
    if 4 <> length? t [              ; if the tuple doesn't have exactly 4 parts
        return off                   ; return 'false'  
    ]
    s = form as-ipv4 t/1 t/2 t/3 t/4 ; is the input equal to its parts converted to an IP adress
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>45</s> 21 bytes

```
Ｉ∧⁼№θ.³¬Φ⪪θ.¬№Ｅ²⁵⁶Ｉλι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzEvRcO1sDQxp1jDOb8UKFqoo6Ckp6Spo2AMxH75JRpumTklqUUawQU5mUiyIBmIBt/EAg0jUzMdBbB5OZpAyUxNCLD@/99Az8BAz9BAz8jU9L9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 24 bytes by porting @Shaggy's Japt answer. Explanation:

```
    θ                   Input string
   №                    Count occurrences of
     .                  Literal `.`
  ⁼                     Equal to
      ³                 Literal 3
 ∧                      Logical And
       ¬                Logical Not
          θ             Input string
         ⪪              Split on
           .            Literal `.`
        Φ               Filter by
            ¬           Logical Not
               ²⁵⁶      Literal 256
              Ｅ         Map over implicit range
                   λ    Map value
                  Ｉ     Cast to string
             №          Count occurrences of
                    ι   Filter value
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

Comment: Fails for test cases with negative integers like `123.-50.0.12` or `1.1.1.-80`. Everything else seems to work fine. So the `<256` check should be `in [0,255]` instead.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Actually the code to filter out invalid characters wasn't working because I forgot to change the variable in the inner loop. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <del>109</del> 93 bytes

```
import re
lambda x:bool(re.match(r'^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$',x))
```

**Explanation**

Each octet can be 0 - 255 :

- starts with 25 and having 0-5 as last digit
- start with 2, has 0-4 as second digit and any digit at the end
- starts with 1, and 00 - 99 as rest digits
- has only 2 digits - 1-9 being the first one and any digit thereafter
- or just a single digit

An octet can end with a (.) or just end, with the condition that it cannot do both , the negative lookahead `(?!$)` takes care of this case

Thanks [@Zachary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55550/zachar%C3%BD) for making me realize I can discard spaces (since it is code golf) 
Thanks [@DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc) for the improvements and making me realize my mistake, its been corrected now.

Comment: Some explanation for this might help.

Comment: `x: re.match`=>`x:re.match`; `, x` => `,x`, and `) is` => `)is` should save 3 bytes. Also, in the regex,  you can use `\d` for each occurrence of `[0-9]`, and `[1]`=>`1`. This seems like a great first post, though!

Comment: `[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]` can become `[1-9]\d|\d` (per Zacharý's advice), which can become `[1-9]?\d`. Also, instead of testing `re.match(...)is not None`, you can do `bool(re.match(...))` since match objects are truthy and `None` is falsey. :)

Comment: Hmm. Actually, this fails on the test case `1.2.3.4.5` (and also `1.2.3.4.`, which isn't in the official list of test cases), because it can match a period instead of end-of-string after the fourth number.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki), <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```
^
.
^(\.(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])?\d)){4}$
```

Port of [*@OlivierGrégoire*'s Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174478/52210), so make sure to upvote him!
-2 bytes thanks to *@Neil*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VVDBTsMwDL37K3YYohX4yXaTbTkgToiPWDux0R24MGnigET59pKkS1VkRbGf37Nfcj1/fXwedbyrXt/GA4EOVYvK/F7Yd0Nl8XbdoG0/7JVDVz@3fV3/uN/1OCp0I1CBOSENFssdIkjmfW4JGkeaIAilMkZuLk4Wiigag9tGtqFBIk@TEyFCa5RBIYSJdBNiIh1xwjt6UmvAPqFqxP8csgeb34BlYZEXHpP1ktFcL665z3JLHmbFS8niivLmb6X7y3WlT8pMpKscpI85ivDMO6F5P6YPcH8).

**Explanation:**

```python
^
.                           # Prepend a dot "." before the (implicit) input
^...$                       # Check if the entire string matches the following regex
                            # exactly, resulting in 1/0 as truthy/falsey:
 (                          #  Open a capture group
  \.                        #   A dot "."
    (25[0-5]                #   Followed by a number in the range [250,255]
    |(2[0-4]|         ) \d) #   or by a number in the range [200,249]
    |(      |1\d|     ) \d) #   or by a number in the range [100,199]
    |(          |[1-9]) \d) #   or by a number in the range [10,99]
    |(                )?\d) #   or by a number in the range [0,9]
 )                          #  Close capture group
  {4}                       #  This capture group should match 4 times after each other
```

Comment: My attempt (which I didn't post because the question got put on hold at the time) was the same length, but didn't have the `\d` group optimisation, so you can save two bytes because you don't need the `M` specification on the last line.

Comment: I managed to get Retina down to 42 bytes by porting the Perl 6 answer but this answer also works in 0.8.2 which my port doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
∞n·Θ3ª&JH‼∙*~Γ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ec6efae933a6264a4813f92a7ee2&i=%221.160.10.240%22%0A%22192.001.32.47%22%0A%221.2.3.%22%0A%221.2.3%22%0A%220.00.10.255%22%0A%221.2.%24.4%22%0A%22255.160.0.34%22%0A%22.1.1.1%22%0A%221..1.1.1%22%0A%221.1.1.-0%22%0A%22.1.1.%2B1%22%0A%221+1+1+1%22%0A%221%22%0A%2210.300.4.0%22%0A%2210.4F.10.99%22%0A%22fruit+loops%22%0A%221.2.3.4.5%22&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
VB      constant 256
r       [0 .. 255]
'|*     coerce and string-join with "|"; i.e. "0|1|2|3 ... 254|255"
:{      parenthesize to "(0|1|2|3 ... 254|255)"
]4*     make 4-length array of number pattern
.\.*    string join with "\\."; this forms the complete regex
|Q      is the input a complete match for the regex?
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=VB++%09constant+256%0Ar+++%09[0+..+255]%0A%27%7C*+%09coerce+and+string-join+with+%22%7C%22%3B+i.e.+%220%7C1%7C2%7C3+...+254%7C255%22%0A%3A%7B++%09parenthesize+to+%22%280%7C1%7C2%7C3+...+254%7C255%29%22%0A]4*+%09make+4-length+array+of+number+pattern%0A.%5C.*%09string+join+with+%22%5C%5C.%22%3B+this+forms+the+complete+regex%0A%7CQ++%09is+the+input+a+complete+match+for+the+regex%3F&i=%221.160.10.240%22%0A%22192.001.32.47%22%0A%221.2.3.%22%0A%221.2.3%22%0A%220.00.10.255%22%0A%221.2.%24.4%22%0A%22255.160.0.34%22%0A%22.1.1.1%22%0A%221..1.1.1%22%0A%221.1.1.-0%22%0A%22.1.1.%2B1%22%0A%221+1+1+1%22%0A%221%22%0A%2210.300.4.0%22%0A%2210.4F.10.99%22%0A%22fruit+loops%22%0A%221.2.3.4.5%22&a=1&m=2)

Comment: Surprised to know that you made the language Stax! it is working well.

Comment: Thanks!  The space of golfing languages is surprisingly crowded, and I'm not sure if stax can justify its own existence on its merits, but my main goal was just to see if I could do it and maybe learn something.  It ended up being more fun than expected.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF/\./`, 47 bytes

```perl
$\=@F==4&&!/[^0-9.]/;$\&&=!/^0./&&$_<256for@F}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxtbBzdbWRE1NUT86zkDXUi9W31olRk3NVlE/zkBPX01NJd7GyNQsLb/Iwa22@v9/Qz0DINIz/JdfUJKZn1f8X9fXFChk8F@34L@um36Mnj4A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
~(K`

255*
["^(("|'|]")\.?\b){4}$"L$`
$.`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBNb8IwDL37V6CqiALzk50mQA/TTogD/IOxqXwduICEdpg02F/vkpRUnawo9vN79ktup6/zZafNsFjVzW@xromMcxN6zz6LIruP7h/ZeIu37X78Yx95tslrylE3jUJnAhUYK6SV8eUCHgzq2BKUljRAEAqlj9jsnSgUUZQGdu7ZBiUCuZ0cCB7KkQZVVdWSnkK0pB32OOBIakqwC6ga4n8O2YGNm4GlZ5F7HoP1lFFX966uz/JMpp1imTK/Ir35W2l0vQ30VZmJdBCD9CVGEp54IdTtR/sB9g8) Based on a previous version of @nwellnhof's Perl 6 answer, but 1 byte saved by stealing the `\.?\b` trick from @Deadcode's answer. Explanation:

```
K`
```

Clear the work area.

```
255*
```

Insert 255 characters.

```
["^(("|'|]")\.?\b){4}$"L$`
$.`
```

Generate the range 0..255 separated with `|`s, prefixed with `^((`, and suffixed with `)\.?\b){4}$`, thus building the regular expression `^((0|1|...255)\.?\b){4}$`.

```
~(
```

Evaluate that on the original input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁹ḶṾ€ṗ4j€”.ċ
```

A monadic link accepting a list of characters which yields \$1\$ if it's a valid address and \$0\$ otherwise. Builds a list of all \$256^4=4294967296\$ addresses and then counts the number of occurrences of the input therein.

**[Here's similar @ Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R45aHO7Y93LnvUdOahzunm2QB6UcNc/WOdP///1/J0FTPQM9Qz9BACQA)** that uses \$16\$ (`⁴`) rather than \$256\$ (`⁹`), since the method is so inefficient!

#### How?

```
⁹ḶṾ€ṗ4j€”.ċ - Link: list of characters, S
⁹           - literal 256
 Ḷ          - lowered range = [0,1,2,...,254,255]
  Ṿ€        - unevaluate €ach = ['0','1',...,['2','5','4'],['2','5','5']]
    ṗ4      - 4th Cartesian power = ALL 256^4 lists of 4 of them
            -               (e.g.: ['0',['2','5','5'],'9',['1','0']])
        ”.  - literal '.' character
      j€    - join for €ach (e.g. ['0','.','2','5','5','.','9','.','1','0'] = "0.255.9.10")
          ċ - count occurrences of right (S) in left (that big list)
```

Comment: Why does the version with 65,536 IPs take 1.8 seconds? o_O

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>287</s> 197 bytes

```c
#import<regex.h>
g;f(char*s){regex_t r;g=regcomp(&r,"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$",1);g=regexec(&r,s,0,0,0);return !g;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9NboMwEIXXcAqXNpVNiGUbaBU56UWAVsgFhwU/MjSKRDi7OyYsuq1G9nue@UYzVgetlLXPTTv0ZjqZSlc3evnwtayxupQmHMm8Jr8mZKQ@g1d9O@BXEwWfGGfscCzuGYf7Yfkqs1juAlyyZUUKmhYkzymZ4@W/bS9BxMljeHWrlBs@RswFkaaafkyHnrRcbNNNqC2bDjtTGq0i5P6AwhAeV4L82ffq3qC13qAz4hLktKLg9nuCgPAGA/UaB7sRkN133gWRQ65ZU0SoxpslRPre4nvbAhh28RdrORU0ppZRxihnVKSphUP5G2RonFiO1rD8KADhNBY0eYcuBzg@YX97fwE)

Thanks to [Logern](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36046/logern) for the big save !

Comment: [197 bytes Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9NboMwEIXXcAqXNpVNiGUbaBU56UWAVsgFhwU/MjSKRDi7OyYsuq1G9nue@UYzVgetlLXPTTv0ZjqZSlc3evnwtayxupQmHMm8Jr8mZKQ@g1d9O@BXEwWfGGfscCzuGYf7Yfkqs1juAlyyZUUKmhYkzymZ4@W/bS9BxMljeHWrlBs@RswFkaaafkyHnrRcbNNNqC2bDjtTGq0i5P6AwhAeV4L82ffq3qC13qAz4hLktKLg9nuCgPAGA/UaB7sRkN133gWRQ65ZU0SoxpslRPre4nvbAhh28RdrORU0ppZRxihnVKSphUP5G2RonFiO1rD8KADhNBY0eYcuBzg@YX97fwE "Try It Online")Saved bytes by removing types, replacing REG_EXTENDED with its int value, removing some of the includes, instead using import, renaming variables and removing the ternary in the return.

Comment: [188 bytes](https://tio.run/##lY7dboQgEIWv5Smo7TbgsgRQ22zc9kXUNoaq64U/Qbtp4vrsdGD3orfNBM5h5ptw9KHV2trHrp9Gs5xM3dY//PyOGqLPlYlmuvrW54JNBk6P/USeDQs/CMnF4Vhecwn3zUovq9quClxy76oUNC1pUXC6xtt/155CJil8vXyb4cFnqbVLMDPhimab7YYF91U3EGcq02qGXXgcRfC4UIxWFDSjwX7e4TcsM5CTR8Ht9xQDEUwG5g0JdzMgu69iCJlDLnlXMtyQu6U0Q8GGglsiTCAB2qyVXPGYW8GF4FJwlaYWDpcv0OFxYiX2ZeVRASJ5rHjyClsOcHwi/u7@Ag "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>25</s> 16 bytes

```
a~=X,256RL4J"\."
```

Takes the candidate IP address as a command-line argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/sc42QsfI1CzIx8RLKUZP6f///4Z6hmYGeoYGekYmBgA) or [Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##TU7LCsIwELz3K8LiTTts0qSlBz16EL14ElTEi1AotPg4if56zKYPy5AwM8zuTlu1/gJS6UoR3v76XR4WxuX7rd3QCeQ/aqeOiSINnTM0w1gm0aUBs0ZmYItowCDDyIRwSMQR5wZ/Bis0OHEfI4saWtCFplyQ8piYd7aKiDR@YUs4ZMG9smu5WpYib/dX9VR107SPf0sLN7SYvL6ygJKz92n9Aw)

#### Explanation

Regex solution, essentially a port of [recursive's Stax answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174518/16766).

```
                  a is 1st cmdline arg (implicit)
    ,256          Range(256), i.e. [0 1 2 ... 255]
   X              To regex: creates a regex that matches any item from that list
                  i.e. essentially `(0|1|2|...|255)`
        RL4       Create a list with 4 copies of that regex
           J"\."  Join on this string
 ~=               Regex full-match
a                 against the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 59 bytes

Passes special cases not in test with periods at start/end

```r
function(s)length(a<-scan(,t=s,s,,,"."))==4&all(a%in%0:255)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZNNboMwEIX3PcWINhWoZAoEWqUq297DBZNYMjayTaRUvTs1P0kJDUnKbFi8z/Nm/KyaIm2KWmSGSeFqj1OxMVuXvC91RoTrm1T72vd9Bx3PS9P4kXDukgUTi@AtShKvKVwnxPAlwDDAKA4c7x4AvgGMqim0v3dWYZWdJsBVfF4RriMMghBXEcavncQqCsI17cUupyRnYgNfVEkNlaKaCuN1KEa4wuOxY0gKvgezVZRCzjbM6F@g1w/fTZi130@ZJAP8L4sPGI96XusIRORAQFc0Y4SD3pefkp@ciWFb4zFuHH4KTrBSKmoxIga2oorJ/AC3tQxm4Wt@n8L5HVxgQ@hqnhXy1OfJ7c7tRophMz1jw2kvOMbjdBNmR7gNrNxRBW3yByb@aDOxXp@PBBOWYjlkW6JIZqjq/RWqZga4lJU@z9VliYijeMeYHGeaaI2UUBKxP2zgWdTl56ET/nl6E7qHgBjQhqh@FWMGL0NU5F7zAw)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 89 bytes

```
(_,r=`(${[...Array(256).keys()].join`|`})`)=>RegExp(`^${(r+'\\.').repeat(3)+r}$`).test(_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc3BCoJAEAbge88hOIM57FqKF4MO@QBds1yxRTRxZZVIzGe37Bhp/Mfvn/mL5J40qc7r1q7UVY5hMEK81oEAoz8R0V7rpAPH9ZBusmsAz1SovBJPMaDAYHeU2eFRg7gYPWjLjCIykbSsZdLCBi09GAKplU0LMY6pqhpVSipVBiGYnLjHiDNytsxEXH3xe3S5YP95MDEterqEjM8ro09@Cpe278@o47oLl1MmGF8)

Create `RegExp` capture groups from indexes of an array having `length` `256` for range `0-255` joined with `|` and followed by escaped `.` character (`^(0|1...|255)\.(0|1...|255)\.(0|1...|255)\.(0|1...|255)$`) repeated `3` times closing with joined array followed by `$` to match end of string, return `true` or `false` result of input passed to `RegExp.prototype.test()`.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>123</s> 107 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpNDsIgEAbQPafQDYXNFyp2o5l4FINm1DFUiGDiTz071vV798fh1VqgM9eC4yWNWTEFlBylduiUyQu35adUKyfDGEM2elPTXiyuSW5zsUsKKs8WYtx9JpmMA1bDYIlI8K9frRlF3ky0tq31Hh49vHM/)

```
a=gets.chomp
e=a.split'.'
(p 0;exit)if(e.map(&:to_i).join'.')!=a
p(e.all?{|i|(0..255)===i.to_i}&&e.size==4)
```

This could definitely be shorter, probably with a regex of some sort, but I wanted to do it without a regex.

Thanks to MegaTom for Array#all?

`0` or `false` is falsy; `true` is truthy.

Explanation:

The input is taken from stdin. It's split into an array of the numbers (as strings) on the periods.

If the array isn't the same as it is with the elements converted to numbers and back to strings, the program outputs `0` and exits. This eliminates cases with leading zeros and illegal characters.

The array is converted to an array of true/false values representing whether the value is between 0 and 255, inclusive.

`true` is outputted if the array is only true values, meaning that all the numbers were between 0 and 255, and only if it has exactly 4 elements, meaning that there were 4 original numbers. `false` is outputted otherwise, meaning invalid numbers (higher than 255) or too many numbers.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG. Could you possibly provide a link to an online interpreter for ease of verifying your solution?

Comment: I've added a TIO link. The default input is 255.255.255.255.

Comment: I think the `all?` method could make this code a good bit shorter.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

**APL(NARS), 45 chars**

```
{'...'≢⍵∼⎕D:0⋄4≠+/255≥⍎¨a←⍵⊂⍨⍵≠'.':0⋄a≡⍕¨⍎¨a}
```

test

```
  f←{'...'≢⍵∼⎕D:0⋄4≠+/255≥⍎¨a←⍵⊂⍨⍵≠'.':0⋄a≡⍕¨⍎¨a}  
  f '1.160.10.240'   
1
  f '192.001.32.47' 
0
  f '1.2.3.'
0
  f '1.2.3'
0
```

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 53 bytes

```
@(ping -4 %1&echo g 255.255.255.255 w)|find/c"g %1 w"
```

Disconnect your Internet connection first to avoid the standard loophole.

I can't find information on how to avoid `^"`.

Comment: Deleted cuz can't handle 255.255.255.255

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS) 50 chars, 100 bytes

```
{'...'≢⍵∼⎕D:0⋄4≠≢w←⍵⊂⍨⍵≠'.':0⋄w≢⍕¨m←⍎¨w:0⋄256>⌈/m}
```

test:

```
  p←{'...'≢⍵∼⎕D:0⋄4≠≢w←⍵⊂⍨⍵≠'.':0⋄w≢⍕¨m←⍎¨w:0⋄256>⌈/m}
  {⍞←'[',⍵,'=',(p ⍵),']'⋄⍬}¨a 
[1.160.10.240= 1 ][192.001.32.47= 0 ][1.2.3.= 0 ][0.00.10.255= 0 ][1.2.$.4= 0 ][255.160.0.34= 1 ][.1.1.1= 0 ][1..1.1.1= 0 ][1.1.1.-0= 0 ][.1.1.+1= 0 ][1 1 1 1= 0 ][1= 0 ][10.300.4.0= 0 ][10.4F.10.99= 0 ][fruit loops= 0 ][1.2.3.4.5= 0 ][0.0.0.0= 1 ][0.0 0.0.= 0 ][1.23..4= 0 ][1:1:1:1:1:1:1:1= 0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 87 bytes

A port of [@Olivier Grégoire's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174478/110802).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVJRT8IwEH7fr7gsGLdAL23Z1BGHUeODDyZGE1@EhwoFZ8ZG1mowwG/HtkMpptl6933ffevtqiaiFLtisawbDcom@KmLEhdCT96Lao5Pci5XQVC/fciJhgdRVCBXWlZTBdfLJax3X6KE2eBZN0adD2/qupSiylU@jEIMoQsqbs2kisJoNMKIp6@UpONNxM2ejDdsNJpuXhnJxvGVCeN4nWzDeAdgnQv1Ispiev/4lUAOMwhaWEulb4WSyoDXTSO@I0MAhAzZGUVGkSc07Jk84wa5QIPblKepE1DsJ462BDqlBWkbWpX3/PpQyrDPMTlvKzn2cV/YfnGvNEQHPfcsy/4KDlb4VyDwDSc4dRTvI0ktx7jNyf92SIqEp2dI6HE/5Lihfbe/iY199DjytYQe4q7vcecl5gDev1s55rRugOWMEJs4FtxyYc8tz02SC3o4lDmAGV4cmNfM2ER2tnBJDjOOYe2mawffSPVZajN172K4ithJluYW6rKKZmHHgicsVQPotEWhlWyDbbD7AQ)

```scala
val f:String=>Boolean=s=>("." + s).matches("(\\.(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\\d|[1-9])?\\d)){4}")
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
'./Ẋl4=ɠL€ṘxƇp&
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPScuJTJGJUUxJUJBJThBbDQlM0QlQzklQTBMJUUyJTgyJUFDJUUxJUI5JTk4eCVDNiU4N3AlMjYmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lMjIxLjE2MC4xMC4yNDAlMjImZmxhZ3M9ZQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
'./Ẋl4=ɠL€ṘxƇp&  '# Implicit input
'./              '# Split the input on "."s
   Ẋ              # Store this in x without popping
    l4=           # Check if the length equals 4
       ɠL         # Push the range [0..255]
         €Ṙ       # Convert each to a string
           xƇp    # Check if each of the values in x
                  # is in this list of strings
                  # (NOTE: this checks three things at once:
                  #   1. all the parts are numbers
                  #   2. all of them are in the range [0..255]
                  #   3. none of them have leading zeros)
              &   # Check if both things are true
                  # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 81 bytes

```go
import."net/netip"
func f(s string)bool{a,e:=ParseAddr(s)
return e==nil&&a.Is4()}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVJda9swFIU96lfcmqbYzL2TE3ddMjQobIO9lH7kbStDTaVg5siuJEOH8S_ZSxj0R-xf7HX7NZXs9CFKysXYPuf66Nzr8-v3slr_qfniB18KWPFCkWJVV9piJFc2emysPH737_IZU8K-cVdRR0Q2agEyNmCsLtQyua2qsuWpmLELro04u7vTsUmIFrbRCgRjqiiPjjh-MXmcdIPw_1d_7c9awNyLNAsLbaHqjeB7EA81eNVuOMubixNoiRXGGpgx-Hozb0kbZZi9pZhRHOc0SgHAaYku9cx0jJRmOBljftpTkpdmw-EYJ7gPDDDqJHr1k5M93YeYB6jr6w1RnOTbdjDztSPyAuzrmAZwj77eaYa-QjR8d47cKDmGoo7IP_sRp9OAkbopLJRVVZu968sx3Imfm2LwHxwAHt7VmODO_rLZVm2xHSEXLhy2VHHEGIPr-dnVHNxTlBBZafieWh8MzZVL85CTlvBFD8rYootXQgoJHjpgYNFnrIVeU8bR6B7YBxhZiEc2-abc0f0nqe9Ph-4EOudiywR8Ov8IGxObYK_Xw_0J)

Uses the `net/netip` package from the standard library.

## [Go](https://go.dev), 119 bytes

```go
import."regexp"
func f(s string)bool{return MustCompile(`^(\.(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])?\d)){4}$`).MatchString("."+s)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVLBjtMwEJU4-isGayvZ2nTkpC7QRQEhWG67QmxvbWFDNi4RaRISR4DSfMleKiQ-gr_gCl-DnZRD3aI5OHlv8uaN8-6_r4vdzzKKP0XrBDZRmpN0UxaVRqo2mv5otBo_-f3lH1Yl6-RrSYlq8hgUq6HWVZqv-YeiyNoq0U2Vw1VT65fFpkyzhN2-Y0tkwXQhxtPVlgXmlKutv7zbLvzxbMWfL-84b2V3dsvxKtLxx5tej1Gk5zXvhvF_HvzS38oE5nZaE2to07zcT34Kxg_Y8d1gyq7AOLREJ7Wu4SKExWrekpb66D8S6AsMpKAeABitpPMsMwtQCB8nAcrHPaWirN5zGOAET4EOJoxErz6dnug-Q-mgpq83JHAiD-2gb-tI5D-wrbFw4B49P2qGvlzUfTeOzCoSXVFDyNd2xdnMYVTVpBqyoijrk9cn0b0Tu7dA5z8YACx8rDHBo_vzLw7qgO0IeWPCobOc0TAM4Wb-4u0czBPlRBUVvPe0DUYV5SbzQ05aEsU9qJhGEy9OUgUWehiCRpuxFnpNxejoM4TPYKSBjTRf5mZ0_4ln-72hm0NnXByYgMvrV7A3sQ_2bjecfwE)

Using the regex from [@Olivier Grégoire's post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174478/77309).

Answer (score -1):

## PHP, <strike>27</strike> <strike>26</strike> 24 Bytes

```
<?=+!!ip2long($argv[1]);
```

Based on @rexkogitans and @nwellnhof solutions
Fails for 0.0.0.0 because PHP internal function 0.0.0.0 is not considered a valid IP address
[Try it!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WW1Exs8AoJz8vXUMlsSi9LNowVtP6////BkaGxibGZgA)